# Compilation products portability

Tags: c++, compilation

I want to ask you about object files (*.o, *.obj) and static libraries (*.a, *.lib). As far as I know, static libraries must match with compilers, so they are compiler-specific. Is it true? How does it look like if it comes to object files? Object files are consisted of binarny code, so it is tempting to assume that I can use them with all compillers. I am looking forward your answears.

Comment: Object files and libraries are usually made for a specific *target*. It is usually possible to use object files made for a specific target by one compiler, together with a object files made for the same specific target by another compiler. The important thing is that both compilers use the same [*Application Binary Interface (ABI)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

Comment: _"Object files are consisted of binarny code, so it is tempting to assume that I can use them with all compillers."_ Why's that? They don't exist in a vacuum! They almost always link with some runtime, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, static libraries must match with compilers, so they are compiler-specific. Is it true?

Yes, that's true.

> Object files are consisted of binarny code, so it is tempting to assume that I can use them with all compillers.

Static libraries aren't anything else than accumulated `.o` files, so no other rule applies for these.

Comment: Could you go into more detail why static libraries list match with compillers? I trying to understand it

Comment: @KasataAta It's just what [@someprogrammerdude commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190432/compilation-products-portability/52190479?noredirect=1#comment91330713_52190432) and that's already true for `.o` files. As mentioned a static library is just a collection of `.o` files.

Answer (score -1):

VISUAL STUDIO ANSWER

For visual studio, a `.lib` is just a container of `.obj` and so which one doesn't change the answer.

Also whether a LIB must match a specific version of the compiler depends. With ltcg they must match. Without it ... it depends. A clean, c interface library probably is ok to use with different versions of a compiler. When C++/STL gets in the mix things can start to go wrong. So the best advice is just use the same version - don't risk it. You may get away with it for a while but unless you're very careful you'll eventually trip up.

And by the same version generally the same *major* version is suffice - VS team really try to not break binary compat in minor version updates

No idea about .o or .a

Comment: _"No idea about .o or .a"_ Merely the same as `.obj` and `.lib`.